# single sp to connect multiple Idps in shibboleth SSO

Tags: shibboleth

I have a requirement of connecting single service provider to connect set of multiple Idps in shibboleth SSO. After googling i get to know it can be achieved Using Embedded disovery service.After installation and configurations i'm getting redirected to idp select page, but there are no idps in the list.when i checked the idpselect_config file, there is a datasource ="/Shibboleth.sso/DiscoFeed". Discoveryfeed file which is json formatted containg idp's metadata. I tried by converting idp metadata xml file to json formated file and copied to the same folder to shibboleth-ds(where embedded dscovery files located). Still no use. No Idps are in the Idp select dropdown.

Can any one tell me how to do this or  do we get any sample discovery feed file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/Shibboleth.sso/DiscoFeed` is a handler provided by Shibboleth SP. That handler will return a JSON formatted list of all of the IdPs that your SP is integrated with, by consuming the metadata of the IdP.

Have you configured your SP with `<MetadataProvider>` elements for each IdP's XML metadata?

Basically, the Embedded Discovery Service works in conjunction with the handler from Shib SP to provide the drop-down.

What is returned when you browse to `https://{your-server}/Shibboleth.sso/DiscoFeed`?

Comment: After i providing <MetadataProvider> element for each IDP in Configuration file i'm able to see all the IDPs in a dropdown. when i browse https://{your-server}/Shibboleth.sso/DiscoFeed, now i'm able to see the IDP entities and other details. Thanks Kellen